# Как сделать отслеживание включения компьютера?

Tags: бот, сеть, пк

Подскажите,пожалуйста, как и с помощью чего можно написать код, который уведомлял бы, во сколько включился ПК и какие еще НЕ включились. У нас в компании 18 компьютеров, они в 9:00 утра уже должны 100% быть включены. Хочется потом интегрировать с ТГ-ботом, чтобы бот с помощью кода сам проверял на наличие включенных пк по адресам и писал, какой включен, а какой нет.
Просто для понимания надо хотя бы представление иметь как можно такое сделать :\

Comment: Можно написать скрипт на питоне, который бы отправлял имя пк и время загрузки на сервер, и кинуть его в автозапуск. А серверная часть скрипта, написанная на том же питоне, могла бы логировать эти сообщения и отправлять в телеграм...

Comment: zabbix. Позволит ещё много чего, кроме этого.

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать скрипт PowerShell используя:

```
(gcim Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime
```

или cmd через:

```
wmic path Win32_OperatingSystem get LastBootUpTime
```

Или например, просматривать камеры наблюдения,
Можно прийти пораньше и отправить сообщение телеграфом.

Comment: Спасибо. А не подскажите, как сделать, чтобы эти данные я получал на основной пк? Т.е. мне как то надо получать информацию о включении рабочего ПК на хост\сервер после чего эта информация передавалось в бот, это с помощью какой либо программы надо сделать? В интернете я не смог информацию найти, возможно не правильно ищу, хотя подбирал ключевые слова. Я только учусь в этом, простите ^_^

Comment: Просто именно одно до конца не понимаю, как взаимосвязать рабочий ПК с сервером\хостом\своим пк

Comment: Это зависит от ваши знаний, умений, вот вы что умеете?

Comment: Вопрос сложный конечно. Мне если дать какую то 1 задачу, я в ней пытаюсь максимум разобраться не исходя из своих других возможностей. Если Вы допустим скажите, что да с помощью программы "X" я пойду делать все возможное чтобы с этой программой X получилось то, что я хотел. Я не особо просто много чего умею, как я выше сказал, я только учусь)